# Error handling to restart Word from Excel inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, ms-word

I'm often opening, from Excel, all Word documents inside a folder.

And sometimes during the treatments, Word crash without throwing an error.

So I've added a bit of error handling to restart Word and reopen the doc I was working on.

---

I'm just wondering if I'm doing it properly, or if I should go further like :

1. Test the error number
2. If it's 462 : *The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable*, go to RestartWord
3. If it's something else, show the error message

It may also not be only Error 462, but I don't have any other examples for this.

---

My code :

```
Private Sub Update_Word_DocMs_In_Folder(ByVal FolderToScan As String, _
                                            ByVal PathTxtWithInfo As String)
Dim oW As Object, NewFile As String
'''Boolean to detect if it was the initial launch
Dim NormalWordLaunch As Boolean
NormalWordLaunch = True
Set oW = OpenOrReopen("Word.Application", NormalWordLaunch)


On Error GoTo RestartWord
    NewFile = Dir(FolderToScan & "*.docm")
    Do While NewFile <> vbNullString
'''ErrHdl: Jump back here after re-creating a Word's instance
ReOpenWordFile:
        Call OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment(oW, FolderToScan & NewFile, PathTxtWithInfo)
        NewFile = Dir()
    Loop
    oW.Quit
On Error GoTo 0

Set oW = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing
Exit Sub
RestartWord:
    If Err.Number <> 462 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error not handled"
        DoEvents
        Resume
    Else
        Set oW = OpenOrReopen("Word.Application", NormalWordLaunch)
        '''ErrHdl: If this isn't the initial launch go back to the loop
        If Not NormalWordLaunch Then Resume ReOpenWordFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Function to handle creating an app instance :

```
Function OpenOrReopen(ByVal ClassName As String, NormalLaunch As Boolean) As Object
    Set OpenOrReopen = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    '''Check if there is already an instance
    Set OpenOrReopen = VBA.GetObject(, ClassName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If OpenOrReopen Is Nothing Then
        '''If there isn't any instance, create one
        Set OpenOrReopen = VBA.CreateObject(ClassName)
    Else
        '''If detected instance is visible, create a new one
        If OpenOrReopen.Visible Then Set OpenOrReopen = VBA.CreateObject(ClassName)
    End If
    '''Set instance to be hidden
    OpenOrReopen.Visible = False
    OpenOrReopen.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen = False

    '''For ErrHdl: Change boolean the 1st time
    If NormalLaunch Then NormalLaunch = False
End Function
```

Code for treatment :

```
Sub OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment(WordApp As Object, _
                                 ByVal FileFullName As String, _
                                 ByVal PathTxtWithInfo As String)
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Set oDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileFullName)
    With oDoc
        Do While .ReadOnly
            DoEvents
        Loop
        '''Some treatment to update doc's properties
        WordApp.Run "Properties_Updating.Properties_Update", PathTxtWithInfo
        DoEvents
        .Save
        .Close
    End With 'oDoc
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you closing the word application at all? during the loop I mean.

Comment: @Raystafarian : Nope, I just close it once I'm done processing the documents. So it's just unexpected crashes that happens inside the loop.

Comment: I'd use a `SELECT CASE` rather than `IF` on your error handler - easier to group any errors then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `Update_Word_DocMs_In_Folder` isn't following the `PascalCase` convention that's otherwise observed by your code; underscores should generally be avoided in procedure names in VB6/VBA (especially for `Public` members), because underscores have a very specific meaning in identifier names:

```
[Interface]_[Member]
[EventSource]_[EventName]
```

So `Properties_Update` is a problem, or can become one.

I find the indentation hard to follow, it doesn't seem consistent: some statements aren't indented, others are, but there's no apparent rhyme or reason to it.

The `Call` statement is obsolete and its use isn't consistent either; I'd remove it.

> ```
> Call OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment(oW, FolderToScan & NewFile, PathTxtWithInfo)
> ```

Becomes:

```
OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment oW, FolderToScan & NewFile, PathTxtWithInfo
```

The `RestartWord` label is misleading: it's just an error handler subroutine, it doesn't *necessarily* "restart Word".

`oDoc` and `oW` have that useless and annoying [Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) prefix ("o" for "object", right?) and the identifiers are rather poorly named. I would've had `wordApp` instead of `oW` (funny just noticed that's quite exactly what another procedure is calling it), and `oDoc` is declared and assigned to `Nothing`, but it's never assigned an *actual* object reference, never passed `ByRef` to anything, and never referenced either: it's not used, and should be removed.

Not sure why `CreateObject` is being fully-qualified with the `VBA` standard library identifier - seems rather arbitrary. Why isn't `MsgBox` fully-qualified then?

I find this a bit dangerous:

> ```
> MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error not handled"
> DoEvents
> Resume
> ```

If the error is unknown and unhandled, IMO the right thing to do is to gracefully halt execution, not enter a potentially infinite "try that again in an unknown error state" loop.

> ```
> If Not NormalWordLaunch Then Resume ReOpenWordFile
> ```

I don't like this jumping into a loop body. If `OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment` is what's throwing error 462, then `OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment` is what should be *handling* error 462 - I'd make the procedure a `Function` that returns `False` when that error is thrown and the Word instance needs to be reset.

Honestly, that procedure-that-should-be-a-function *wants* its own error handling: it can blow up given an invalid path/filename, or `Documents.Open` fails for whatever reason, or there's no `Properties_Updating` module, or there's no `Properties_Update` macro, or `.Save` fails - so many things can go wrong in that scope, and all of it is just bubbling back up to the calling code's loop body - that's why you have all this jumping-around.

Handle these errors in `OpenWordDocAndApplyTreatment`, and the loop body and its error-handling logic can get much more straightforward.

`OpenOrReopen` has its side-effects backwards IMO. I would have returned a `Boolean` and altered an `Optional ByRef outWordApp As Object = Nothing` parameter. The `ClassName` parameter is misleading too: that's a registered `ProgId`, not a `ClassName`. Not sure why a ProgId would be needed though - it *looks* like you could use it to get any registered object, but then there's this:

> ```
> OpenOrReopen.Visible = False
> OpenOrReopen.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen = False
> ```

Which, aside from treating the return value as if it were a declared local variable (a bad practice IMO), assumes things it shouldn't be assuming about the object's members - if it's meant to only work with a `Word.Application`, then don't take a ProgId parameter, hard-code it in (or make it a `Const` somewhere, but don't pretend it's a parameter).